# Polygons not being correctly drawn

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to draw some polygons using coordinates. These coordinates represent relative positions of a number of features along a sequence (x-axis), repeated for multiple conditions (y-axis). These polygons are drawn correctly when the x-axis values are the same, but not when they are different - I must be missing something obvious here about how ggplot draws polygons but can't work it out! (I am very new to using ggplot)

This gives the desired output:

```
ids <- factor(c("cox1", "atp8"))

values <- data.frame(
  id = ids,
  value = c("cox1", "atp8")
)

positions <- data.frame(
  id = rep(ids, each = 4),
  x = c(1, 10, 10, 1, 11, 20, 20, 11,
        1, 10, 10, 1, 11, 20, 20, 11 ),
  y = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2.1, 2.1, 3.1, 3.1, 
        5, 5, 6, 6, 6.1, 6.1, 7.1, 7.1)
)

# Currently we need to manually merge the two together
datapoly <- merge(values, positions, by = c("id"))
p.labs <- p + labs(title = "Mito genomes" , x = "Position (bp)", y = "Individual")
p <- ggplot(datapoly, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = value, group = id)) + 
  coord_fixed(ratio = 5) + 
  scale_y_discrete(limit = c(1.5, 5.5), labels = c("1234", "14"))

p
p.labs
```

[image: How polygons should look]

But when I change the x coordinates for the 2nd condition ("14") the polygons become joined:

```
ids <- factor(c("cox1", "atp8"))

values <- data.frame(
  id = ids,
  value = c("cox1", "atp8")
)

positions <- data.frame(
  id = rep(ids, each = 4),
  x = c(1, 10, 10, 1, 11, 20, 20, 11,
        2, 11, 11, 2, 12, 21, 21, 12 ),
  y = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2.1, 2.1, 3.1, 3.1, 
        5, 5, 6, 6, 6.1, 6.1, 7.1, 7.1)
)

# Currently we need to manually merge the two together
datapoly <- merge(values, positions, by = c("id"))
p.labs <- p + labs(title = "Mito genomes" , x = "Position (bp)", y = "Individual")
p <- ggplot(datapoly, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = value, group = id)) + 
  coord_fixed(ratio = 5) + 
  scale_y_discrete(limit = c(1.5, 5.5), labels = c("1234", "14"))

p
p.labs
```

[[image: Polygons are not separate[1]]

My thinking is that for the first case, the polygons are also "joined", but because they are directly above each other you can't see that. How do I specify that these polygons need to remain separate? Many thanks!

EDIT:
An answer below suggests to use groups, which seemed to solve the problem, but when I add more polygons on the x-axis it gets mixed up again (see below)! There is obviously somthing I am fundamentally misunderstanding about how the groups/coordinates need to be specified and I have been racking my brains but can't work it out! Any help would be much appreciated!!:

```
ids <- factor(c("atp6", "atp8", "cob", "cox1", "cox2")) 

values <- data.frame(
  id = ids,
  value = c("atp6", "atp8", "cob", "cox1", "cox2")
)

indiv <- factor(c( "013", "023" ))

individuals <- data.frame(
  id = indiv,
  value = c("013", "023") #, "1008", "101")
)

positions <- data.frame(
  id = rep(ids, each = 4),
x = c(1, 1575, 1575, 1, 1541, 1601, 1601, 1541, 1602, 2288, 2288, 1602, 2290, 2350, 2350, 2290, 2351, 2515, 2515, 2351,
      1, 1557, 1557, 1, 1541, 1603, 1603, 1541, 1605, 2285, 2285, 1605, 2288, 2350, 2350, 2288, 2351, 2509, 2509, 2351),
y = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2.1, 2.1, 3.1, 3.1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2.1, 2.1, 3.1, 3.1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
      4, 4, 5, 5, 5.1, 5.1, 6.1, 6.1, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5.1, 5.1, 6.1, 6.1, 4, 4, 5, 5) 
)

# Currently we need to manually merge the two together
datapoly <- merge(values, positions, by = c("id"))
p.labs <- p + labs(title = "Mito genomes" , x = "Position (bp)", y = "Individual")
datapoly$group1 <- rep(1:10, each = 4)
p <- ggplot(datapoly, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = value, group = group1)) + 
  coord_fixed(ratio = 500) + 
  scale_y_discrete(limit = c(1.5, 5.5, 9.5, 13.5), labels = c("013", "023", "1008", "101"))

p
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The `group` aesthetic determines what coordinates are considered part of the same polygon. By giving each rectangle a unique group identifier, you can prevent this merge.

```
datapoly$group <- rep(1:4, each = 4)
p <- ggplot(datapoly, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(fill = value, group = group)) + 
  coord_fixed(ratio = 5) + 
  scale_y_discrete(limit = c(1.5, 5.5), labels = c("1234", "14"))
```

[image]

EDIT: In case of more groups, this seems to be the plot you want, no?:

```
ids <- factor(c("atp6", "atp8", "cob", "cox1", "cox2"))
positions <- data.frame(
  id = rep(ids, each = 4),
  x = c(1, 1575, 1575, 1, 1541, 1601, 1601, 1541, 1602, 2288, 2288, 1602, 2290, 2350, 2350, 2290, 2351, 2515, 2515, 2351,
        1, 1557, 1557, 1, 1541, 1603, 1603, 1541, 1605, 2285, 2285, 1605, 2288, 2350, 2350, 2288, 2351, 2509, 2509, 2351),
  y = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2.1, 2.1, 3.1, 3.1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2.1, 2.1, 3.1, 3.1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
        4, 4, 5, 5, 5.1, 5.1, 6.1, 6.1, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5.1, 5.1, 6.1, 6.1, 4, 4, 5, 5) 
)

ggplot(positions, aes(x, y, group = id, fill = id)) +
  geom_polygon() +
  coord_fixed(ratio = 500) +
  scale_y_discrete(limit = c(1.5, 5.5, 9.5, 13.5), labels = c("013", "023", "1008", "101"))
```

[image]

It might be that the `merge` operation does something funky to the ordering of your polygons, whereby the `rep(1:10, each = 4)` does not seem to be correct for multiple groups.

Comment: Thank you! That works for this example, but when I scale it up I am still running into problems! I have 16x 4-sided polygons, so I have 64 x-coordinates and 64 y-coordinates, and I set:  datapoly$group <- rep(1:16, each = 4), so that should work right?! But it is again a mess with the polygons all joined up! I have double-checked the coordinates and they are definitely fine, because they work when I use them individually (i.e. I would plot "14" and "1234" in the figure above separately and they look fine). Any ideas?! Thank you!

Comment: That should in theory work if the data is ordered correctly, but are you sure that your coordinates are ordered in groups of 4 rows?

Comment: This works fine:

x = c(1, 1575, 1575, 1, 1541, 1601, 1601, 1541, 1602, 2288, 2288, 1602, 2290, 2350, 2350, 2290, 
      1, 1557, 1557, 1, 1541, 1603, 1603, 1541, 1605, 2285, 2285, 1605, 2288, 2350, 2350, 2288),
y = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2.1, 2.1, 3.1, 3.1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2.1, 2.1, 3.1, 3.1, 
      4, 4, 5, 5, 5.1, 5.1, 6.1, 6.1, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5.1, 5.1, 6.1, 6.1)

datapoly$group1 <- rep(1:8, each = 4)

Comment: But this doesn't work:

x = c(1, 1575, 1575, 1, 1541, 1601, 1601, 1541, 1602, 2288, 2288, 1602, 2290, 2350, 2350, 2290, 2351, 2515, 2515, 2351,
      1, 1557, 1557, 1, 1541, 1603, 1603, 1541, 1605, 2285, 2285, 1605, 2288, 2350, 2350, 2288, 2351, 2509, 2509, 2351),
y = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2.1, 2.1, 3.1, 3.1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2.1, 2.1, 3.1, 3.1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 
      4, 4, 5, 5, 5.1, 5.1, 6.1, 6.1, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5.1, 5.1, 6.1, 6.1, 4, 4, 5, 5) 

datapoly$group1 <- rep(1:10, each = 4)

Comment: so the only difference is I've added 2x polygons on ( x = 2351, 2515, 2515, 2351  / y = 1, 1, 2, 2 ) & ( x = 2351, 2509, 2509, 2351 / y = 4, 4, 5, 5 ) and changed rep from 1:8 to 1:10..?

Comment: Given the last x and y coordinates (of length 10), the following seems to run fine at my end: `df <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, id = rep(1:10, each = 4));
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_polygon(aes(group = id, fill = as.factor(id)))`

Comment: thanks teunbrand - I have updated the question to show what I mean - I have no idea why it is not working for me still! :(

Comment: I think it might have something to do with the merge operation. I've updated my answer for your new example without the merge.

Comment: for me it only works without the merge but with the groups - otherwise they are still connected! If you can update your edited part so that it still includes that I'll mark it correct..? Thank you for all your help!